Magento 2 : Cart price rules applied incorrectly when using parent and child conditions
I'm having an issue with a discount cart price rule for bundle products.
To understand the issue you might want to know we mostly sell USED hardware. The NEW products are not sold much and not much on stock.
I want to give customers a 20% discount for certain bundle products but want to exclude all child products where the product condition NEW is applied.
Example:
I have a bundle product as follows:

HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 (bundle - parent)
HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 Chassis USED (simple option child)
Intel Xeon E5-2690v3 USED (simple option child)
256GB DDR4 RAM USED (simple option child)
P440ar RAID controller USED (simple option child)
Samsung PM893 1.92TB SSD NEW (simple option child)
500W Flex Slot Power Supply USED (simple option child)

I have the following rule:

For some reason it keeps on calculating 20% discount for the whole bundle, including the NEW product.
If i change the rule is not Nieuw to is Nieuw it only calculates the 20% discount to the NEW product. So it seems it does understand which product it should look for but does not accept the is not rule.
I tried it with several different options but cannot seem to get it to work. It only calculates for the complete bundle or only the NEW product. All i want is to exclude the NEW products from the discount but can't find an answer how to solve this.
Anyone who knows how to implement these rules?
